# Azure WebApp instance name unique?

Tags: azure, autoscaling, azure-web-app-service

As my azure web application scales up, are new instances names unique? Or is there a chance that in the past that name already came up?

I'm asking this because I've been considering some reports that requires a unique identifier to group performance logs by and identify how long it takes the application to "cripple" a machine...